# apache directory index behaviour

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

i have a .htacces file containing

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

it suits my need well. Accidentaly once i erased out the filename condiion like so

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to my ill understanding apache grabed the default file (index.html or index.php depending on setup) and inserted that into the action varible can someone plese explain to my how that works as its clearly not the route taken when the line is present.

Comment: more specifically this happends when i only type the domain name and nothing else. like so 'localhost'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the `-f` checks if the request file exists. On top of that, the rewrite engine will loop through all the rules until the URI stops changing. That means the first time around, say you have the request URI: `/foo/bar`

- it's not a directory
- it matches `^(.*)`
- URI gets rewritten to `index.php?action=foo/bar`

next time around, the URI is `/index.php`

- it's not a directory
- it matches `^(.*)`
- URI gets rewritten to `index.php?action=index.php`

next time around, it doesn't change so rewriting stops.

Comment: im not really getting it i get the first time around but in your first example dosnt the rewriting stop there or does it fall thru to your second example? and if u were reffering to two seperate requests (which is what i think u mean by first and second time around) what if i only type in the domain name meaning its just 'http://website' why would it add 'index.php' to action in that instance if in a instance where i type 'http://localhost/smtn' it wouldnt. hope i make sense

Comment: @alex_zander the rewrite engine loops through **all of your rules**, so after the first time, it takes the URI and applies all of your rules **again**, then again, and again, until the URI that it puts into your rules stops changing.

Comment: i would have accepted this answer a long time ago now as it really helped me to understand how this behavior. but what if i type in nothing? can you explain to me the behavior then because it is as i say and it makes my 'action' into the default directory index. so it seems somewhere along that loop Apache is inserting this default index much like it does when i actually just type a directory like say 'localhost'

Comment: i think i have figured it out and i hope it is not a misconfiguration on my part but i have tested these results. it seems that if you type in just the domian name apache(before it looks at modrewrite will use the default index file) making 'http://domain' into 'http://domain/index.html' or whatever its config b4 it uses modrewrite for anything. so `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]`  and you type in 'http://domain' and say you default index file is index.html the first conditon would fail hence no rewrite